# Combing Multiple Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct a pull-down menu that combines data from two arrays -- one is designed to determine and return the third Thursday of upcoming months, and the other is designed to determine and return which of 20 host organizations will host an event on each of the Thursdays.

Here's what I've got -- it gets the Thursdays right but it's not looping back and pulling the names of the successive hosts after the first one (August, 2017 should be host10).  Many thanks in advance.

```
        <body>
<p id="host"></p>

<script>
var date1=new Date(2015,1,1);
var date2=new Date();
var year1=date1.getFullYear();
var year2=date2.getFullYear();
var month1=date1.getMonth();
var month2=date2.getMonth();
if(month1===0){ 
  month1++;
  month2++;
}
var numberOfMonths = (year2 - year1) * 12 + (month2 - month1 - 1); 

var message1 = "- host1";
var message2 = "- host2";
var message3 = "- host3";
var message4 = "- host4";
var message5 = "- host5";
var message6 = "- host6";
var message7 = "- host7";
var message8 = "- host8";
var message9 = "- host9";
var message10 = "- host10";
var message11 = "- host11";
var message12 = "- host12";
var message13 = "- host13";
var message14 = "- host14";
var message15 = "- host15";
var message16 = "- host16";
var message17 = "- host17";
var message18 = "- host18";
var message19 = "- host19";
var message20 = "- host20";


if (numberOfMonths%20 == 0) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message1;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 1) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message2;}  
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 2) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message3;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 3) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message4;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 4) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message5;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 5) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message6;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 6) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message7;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 7) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message8;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 8) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message9;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 9) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message10;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 10) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message11;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 11) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message12;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 12) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message13;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 13) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message14;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 14) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message15;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 15) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message16;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 16) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message17;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 17) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message18;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 18) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message19;}
if (numberOfMonths%20 == 19) {document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = message20;}

document.getElementById("host").innerHTML

var mName=["January","February","March","April","May","June", "July",
"August","September","October","November","December"];
var now=new Date();
now.setDate(1);
var month=now.getMonth();
var year=now.getFullYear();
var html="<select name=\"mySelect\" >\n";
var htmla="<select name=\"mySelect\" >\n";
for(var i=0;i<19;i++){
var firstDay=now.getDay();
var secondMon=8+(1-firstDay+7)%7;
var thirdThurs=15+(4-firstDay+7)%7;
var monthName=mName[now.getMonth()];
html+="<option>"+monthName+" "+secondMon+", "+year+"</option>\n";
htmla+="<option>"+monthName+" "+thirdThurs+", "+year+" "+document.getElementById("host").innerHTML+" </option>\n";

month++;
if(month==12){
month=0;
year++;
}
now=new Date(year,month,1);
}

htmla+="</select>\n";

document.write(htmla);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see, the whole thing can be simplified to:

```
var date = new Date(), result = "<select>";
date.setDate(1);

//a helper function to get the host, may be inlined
function getHost(date){
  var hosts = ["adam","jack"];

 return hosts[ (date.getFullYear()*12 + date.getMonth()) % hosts.length ];
}
//a helper to beautify dates ( may be inlined)
function beautify(date){
 return date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}

for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){ //show 20
 //get the third thursday:
 date.setDate(date.getDate()-date.getDay()+14+4);
 //add an option:
 result +=
 `<option> 
   ${beautify(date)} - ${getHost(date)}
  </option>`;
 //increase month:
 date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
 date.setDate(1);
}

result += "</select>";

document.write(result);
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/qupateroqe/edit?output)

(Notes: the upper code uses string literals (really new, dont work everywhere) , and you should stop working with document.write, go with selecting elems in the DOM and changing them)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, Jonas!  A couple things: it's pulling Weds, not Thurs (easy fix), and it would be great just to have it display the date without all the time detail (again, I can probably fix).  Also, in months that start on Fri or Sat, it pulls the 2nd Thurs not the 3rd Thurs.  And the hosts need to be named and can't just be listed by number.  Again, THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @Jo yeah wasnt shure, edited..  Please check for further errors